# Read all rows of a column and check for delimiter and if found create column with that data (need of 4 columns) in Python

Tags: python, delimiter

I have a column data like below (dtype:object):

```
    Column A 
1324@Hi how are you//where 
are you: I am in London@Cool place@Nice
5649@Hello Christina@Awesome Trip 
@Fantastic
```

Expected output:

```
Col A  Col B                    Col C         Col D
1324   Hi how are you//where    Cool place    Nice
       are you: I am in London
5649   Hello Christina          Awesome Trip  Fantastic
```

I need to check for the delimiter "@" in all rows. Create 4 columns for the first 4 occurrences and for the next four occurences, need to append the data in next row of the same 4 columns as i mentioned in above table.

It would be grateful if any possible solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split for this operation:

```
df.ColumnA.str.split('@').tolist()
```

The output will be a list of lists which can be used to make a new dataframe as per your requirements

```
[['1324',
  'Hi how are you//where are you: I am in London',
  'Cool place',
  'Nice'],
 ['5649', 'Hello Christina', 'Awesome Trip ', 'Fantastic']]
```

to straightaway create a new dataframe that is split accordingly you can use a :

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame(df.name_of_column.str.split('@').tolist(),
                                   columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

P.s the number of columns should be equal to the maximum number @ that are there in any of the elements of the column that you intend to switch.

[image: the output will look like this]

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to achieve your dataframe would be to pass `expand=True` to str.split. This would only work if your data is row-separated. And if you can accept `Col 0` instead of `Col A` this becomes a easy task.

```
df['Column A'].str.split('@', expand=True).add_prefix('Col ')
```

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Column A
1324@Hi how are you//where are you: I am in London@Cool place@Nice
5649@Hello Christina@Awesome Trip@Fantastic'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='|')
df2 = df['Column A'].str.split('@', expand=True).add_prefix('Col ')

print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
  Col 0                                          Col 1         Col 2  \
0  1324  Hi how are you//where are you: I am in London    Cool place   
1  5649                                Hello Christina  Awesome Trip   

       Col 3  
0       Nice  
1  Fantastic
```

Comment: Just I want add this solution ;)